# Delete an Discord Embed after a specific time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to write a moderation Discord bot for my server.
I've added a mute command which works completely fine. But now I want the Embed that is created from the bot to be deleted after a specific time.

This is, what I got at the moment, but it doesn't work and I don't see any errors.

```js
const MuteEmbed = Discord.MessageEmbed();
MuteEmbed.setTitle(" Mute");
MuteEmbed.setDescription(`<@${mentionedMember.id}> wurde gemutet. Nutzer hat ${userLog[mentionedMember.id].length} mutes.\nGrund: ${reason}`);

message.channel.send({ embed: MuteEmbed }).then((message) => {
    message.delete({ timeout: 2000 });
});
```

Help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message` is a parameter that already exists in the global scope. You placing it as a parameter in your `.then()` method's scope simply results in the parameter existing twice inside of the new scope, and making the code have some complications. Rename the message parameter in your `.then()` method to something else, such as `msg`, and make sure to change `message` to the parameter you chose in your deletion method.

```js
.then(msg => {
          msg.delete({ timeout: 2000 });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
message.channel.send({ embed: MuteEmbed })
        .then(message => {
          setTimeout(2000, () => {message.delete()})
        })
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, the embed won't be deleted

Comment: Not sure how this answer solves anything. The `timeout` option in Discord.js's delete method simply completes the same task as if you were to use setTimeout().